# Trouble with installing Selenium(ChromeDriver, Javascript) on Windows 7

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, installation

I'm having trouble installing Selenium and I'm completely lost 
I followed this documentation by the letter and looked around the site and the web for a while now and came to a dead end. Like I said in the title I'm using Chrome and Javascript for this.
[Documentation]http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/index.html

So true with the documentation, the first thing I did was installing the "selenium-webdriver" which I opened up cmd and typed "npm install selenium-webdriver". It responded with saying what directory it installed and the version it installed which was 2.42.1.

After this I installed the ChromeDriver 2.10 from their home download page. After this I unziped the file and moved chromedriver.exe to "node_modules\selenium-webdriver\ChromeDriver" and added it to my systems environmental variables.

So then the next step was to test it, so I copy pasted "npm test selenium-webdriver" into the cmd and got this following error. [Error]https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXPLB.jpg I also tried running ChromeDriver after I kept running into this error and tried it again to get the same result. It doesn't tell me anything other then...
Starting ChromeDriver  on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I suggest you to run your test command using git bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure that you have Mocha installed by running `npm install mocha`.

You will then want to edit the "scripts" section of the package.json file for selenium-webdriver to match the following:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "mocha -R list --recursive test"
},
```

After completing those two steps, you should be able to run your tests with the `npm test selenium-webdriver` command.